# Call a controller method to fill a dropdownlist in a view with an HTML helper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this code in my ASP.NET view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.transporterID, new List<SelectListItem>, "")</p>
```

Which leaves me with an empty select list.

In my controller, I have a method that returns the List object that I want to fill the DropDownList with.

```
    <p>Transporter: @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.transporterID, @Html.Action("methodName", "ControllerName"), "")</p>
```

But this doesn't work. I thought the Html.Action helper was supposed to be used for this kind of situation, but I was wrong. Can anyone tell me how to fill this DropDownList with a controller method? I would prefer not to use the ViewBag or ViewData methods, as I have been specifically instructed to avoid those.

Comment: `@Html.Action("methodName", "ControllerName")` - is that the method that returns your `List<SelectListItem>`?

Comment: Obviously they're called differently in my real code, but yes, that's how I use the HtmlHelper. And it points to the correct method in the right controller.

Comment: ok, well that probably _will_ work, but it would be better in your controller, the example you've given is Razor code i.e in the View. Can you show the contoller code that populates the model that you pass to the view?

Comment: @markpsmith It won't work `Html.Action` renders HTML in the view.

Comment: Yes, I know. What I meant was that it would be better to generate the `List<SelectListItem>` in the controller and pass it to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of items being used to populate the page belongs on the model.

This can be a `List<SelectListItem>`, but doesn't need to be.  It can be any collection to which the `DropDownList` can bind.  For example, if the model has a `List<string>` of values to build the `DropDownList`, it might look like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.transporterID, new SelectList(Model.SomeListOfStrings), "")
```

Ideally the model isn't dependent on things like `SelectList` or `SelectListItem` and just contains the data for the model.  The view would then bind UI elements to that data.  So having a collection of simple data types on the model which gets translated into a `SelectList` in the view like this is the way to go.

The point is that the *model* is what carries this data from the controller to the view.  Not other helper methods on the controller.  Keep in mind the adage that you should "keep your models heavy and your controllers light."  The controller is just routing requests to logic and logic to responses.  The logic itself belongs on the model.

In the absence of a meaningful model for the view, things like `ViewBag` or `TempData` can provide handy stand-ins.  But in an ideal situation there is a strongly-typed model, even if it's a custom view model for just that specific view.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I will create a model for just that list.